# How do I print the bought items at the time of bill?

Tags: java, methods, switch-statement, bluej

I want to print what I've ordered in the starters method with the quantity when printing the bill. Any suggestions as to how I will do it? I have only written an instance of my program since it the entire problem is very large.

Thanks in advance.

```
    static void Bill()
    {

        System.out.println("\f");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************");
        System.out.println("*********************************************************");
        System.out.println("**************************BILL***************************");
        System.out.println(ob);
        System.out.println("Your phone number - "+j);
        int Z = (int)(Math.random()*10000000);
        System.out.println("Bill number is "+Z);
        System.out.println("The total bill amount is Rs."+sum);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Hope you enjoyed. Visit us again soon!");
        Food=0; 
    }

        static void Starters()
    {
        System.out.println("You have selected Starters");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("1. Spring Rolls               - Rs 350");
        System.out.println("2. Onion Rings                - Rs 350");
        System.out.println("3. Fried Raviolli             - Rs 400");
        System.out.println("4. Gorgonzola                 - Rs 400");
        System.out.println("5. Fresh Ricotta Crostini     - Rs 475");
        System.out.println("6. Potato Fritters            - Rs 500");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Enter your desired option");
        starterOption=sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter quantity");
        quantity=sc.nextInt();
        switch(starterOption)
        {
            case 1:
            s1 = quantity * 350;
            break;
            case 2:
            s2 = quantity * 350;
            break;
            case 3:
            s3 = quantity * 400;
            break;
            case 4:
            s4 = quantity * 400;
            break;
            case 5:
            s5 = quantity * 475;
            break;
            case 6:
            s6 = quantity * 500;
            break;
            default:
            System.out.println("You haven't ordered anything");
            break;
        }
        System.out.println("Do you want to order anything else? Y/N");
        A = sc1.next();
        if(A.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
        {
            System.out.println("Do you want to order from the same section? Y/N ");
            F=sc.next();
            if(F.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
            {
                sum=s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6;
                Starters();
            }
            else
            {
                sum=s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6;
                Food_Items();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            sum=s1+s2+s3+s4+s5+s6;
            Bill();
        }
    }
```

Comment: it's a very long code.

Comment: You should have also saved what the customer ordered - and not just the total price.... That's all really. Also read on java's Collections , you have way too many variables. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Comment: Please tell me if something is wrong or against the rules of this site instead of directly down voting my question. I am new to this site!

Comment: @LKTN.25 But the program logic is really simple!

Comment: @Idos I have to use many variables ! My program uses them at various instances. There is no other way out !

Comment: also how do i save what the customer orders? well, that's my query !

Comment: _There is no other way out_ this is really not true.. Maybe you should consider a different approach, as I said, using the many types of collections java has to offer... We unfortunately  cannot write the whole solution for you....

Comment: how about writing a small example, say for starters!

Comment: I am new to java. Using a different approach isn't simply possible for me.

Comment: May have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @hering how 'bout now?

Comment: @java_geek: Reduce the code to your problem, it's easier and faster to read, understand and reply. It's just about the quantity, so remove e.g.  the phone number part.

Comment: @hering how 'bout now?

Comment: @java_geek: Better :)

Comment: @hering I am new here. Thnx for guiding me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several improvement you could do to your code. You have to store what you have already order, if you want to show all the elements on the bill. Each time you order, you can add the element to a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)

You need to store objects in the list, so you could create some objects for your dishes. [Enums](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) seems to be appropiate to your application, this could be some example for the starters:

```
enum Starters {
    SPRING_ROLLS("Spring Rolls", "Rs 350", 5),
    FRIED_RAVIOLLI("Fried Raviolli", "Rs 400", 9),
    ... // All other starters...

    String name;
    String code;
    int price;

    public Starters(String name, String code, String price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.code = code;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public String getCode(){
        return code;
    }

    public int getPrice(){
        return price;
    }
}
```

Then you display your menus like this:

```
for (Starters starter : Starters.values()) {
    System.out.println(starter.getName() + " " starter.getCode()); // Just an example, modify to fit your format
}
```

You are going to have different types of enums and you want to add objects of the same type to the list. You can use an interface for this and make all enums to implement the interface:

```
public interface Orderable {
    public String getName();
    public String getCode();
    public String getPrice();
}
```

You can initialize the list like this:

```
List<Orderable> orders = new ArrayList<>();
```

And add elements to the list like this (The enums need to implement the Orderable interface):

```
orders.add(Starters.SPRING_ROLLS);
order.add(Desserts.CHEESE_CAKE);
...
```

When you want to display the bill, you can iterate over the list and display the orders:

```
int totalPrice = 0;
for (Orderable order : orders) {
    System.out.println(order.getName() + " - " order.getPrice());
    totalPrice += order.getPrice();
}
System.out.println("Total price: ");
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above: this is a very long code for a really simple problem.

When you want to print what was ordered, then you have to save it in a variable, e.g. an array. Or as suggested in a Collection e.g. a List. You can expand your code in the same manner you did it. But it's strongly recommended that you refine your code.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), read the example in the tutorial [in this link](http://www.java67.com/2013/02/10-examples-of-hashmap-in-java-programming-tutorial.html)

A possible solution to your issue could be :-

Declare variable in the class, preferable 'private'

```
private static HashMap<String, Integer> Starters    = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
private static HashMap<String, Integer> Orders      = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

Initialize these using some Init Function or the Constructor of the class with all the possible values for Startres

```
Starters.put("Spring Rolls", 350);
Starters.put("Onion Rings", 400);
```

in the Starters() Function you could use (stripped down sample)

```
    System.out.println("You have selected Starters");
    System.out.println();
    int i = 1;
    String[] mystarters = Starters.keySet().toArray(new String[Starters.keySet().size()]);
    for (String starter : mystarters) {
        System.out.println(i++ + ". " + starter + " : Rs. " + Starters.get(starter));
    }

    System.out.println("Enter your desired option");
    //get option
    System.out.println("Enter quantity");
    //get quantity
    // I am using s. as a prefix for starters, for Main course you could use m. or mc. or something
    Orders.put("s." + mystarters[option - 1], quantity);
```

Of course, you could get the Quantity if this Starter already exists in the order and add to the existing quantity, or ask if it needs to be overwritten.

```
// example
if(Orders.containsKey("s." + mystarters[option - 1]))
   Orders.put(("s." + mystarters[option - 1]), Orders.get("s." + mystarters[option - 1])+quantity);
else
   Orders.put("s." + mystarters[option - 1], quantity);
```

In Bill , you could use the following :-

```
    int sum = 0;
    for (String orderItem : Orders.keySet()) {
        int price = 0;
        int quant = Orders.get(orderItem);
        if (orderItem.startsWith("s.")) {
            orderItem = orderItem.substring(2);
            price = Starters.get(orderItem);
            System.out.println(orderItem + " x " + quant + " = Rs. " + price * quant);
        }
        sum += price * quant;

    }

    System.out.println("Total Price : Rs." + sum);
```